# SCOM 2019 not generating and not sending any e-mail notifications

Tags: notifications, scom

New SCOM 2019 Installation. Notifications (channel, subscription and subscribers) has been configured to send all alerts via email. Alerts are visible in SCOM "Active Alerts" window every day, but no notification has been sent via email.

Port TCP 25 to SMTP mail server is open. Server has been configured to accept anonymous traffic from SCOM Server. Connecting and sending a test message by using Telnet from SCOM 2019 Management Server works well - email has been delivered. Management Server is a part of Notification Resource Pool (dynamic). Wireshark monitoring on TCP 25 shows that SCOM 2019 generates no notification at all. Looks like a serious bug in SCOM 2019 on Win Srv 2019 Datacenter. Maybe similar to SCOM 2012 R2 (when enabling SNMP service on OS level disabled email notifications). I tried to disable SNMP Trap service or enable it but it hasn't change anything. No email notifications has been sent. Wireshark shows that SCOM 2019 has not generated any email. Maybe something is broken in SCOM 2019, email notifications needs to be enabled somewhere (in SCOM Console or from PowerShell) or some OS service needs to be enabled or disabled as email notifications depends on it ?

No errors in Event Logs. Wireshark monitoring shows no activity on TCP 25 on SCOM 2019 Management Server.

Any ideas are more than welcome.

Comment: In Security logs there are reocuring Audit Failures related to SCOM Data Access account stated that: A privileged service was called - SCOM Data Access Account -  Microsoft.MoM.Sdk.ServiceHost.exe - SeTcBPrivilege. Data Access account has full Administrator permissions on OS and SCOM itself as well as on SQL Server OS. I’ve added that account to “Act as a part of operating system” – SeTcbPrivilege. But as I see Audit Failures are still there and no email notifications has been generated – Wireshark shows no TCP 25 traffic at all from SCOM 2019.

Comment: I've installed SCOM 2019 on Windows Server 2019 Standard (instead of Datacenter edition) on my test virtual lab and notifications works well there with a default confiuration out of the box. Maybe it is a bug SCOM 2019 won Windows Server 2019 DC ? Very strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution has been found:

Looks like there may be some bug with “Windows Cluster Management Library” Management Pack (Target: Windows Cluster Service, Cluster Service Discovery)

It was not able to properly discover our cluster based on Windows Server 2012R2 and due to this fact SCOM 2019 entered a rows containing NULLs into OperationsManager.dbo.MT_HealthService table. In the Health Explorer for Management Configuration Service Group we’ve found out that “Delta Syncronization Proces” failed with XML form notification -> Specified Cast is not valid.

To solve the issue we’ve deleted such rows manually and disable/override Object Discovery for a specific object of class: Windows CLuster Service (selecting both cluster nodes).
In a few seconds email notifications started instantly

Next step is to create a ticket to Microsoft to troubleshoot that “Windows Cluster Management Library” Management Pack.